# relate sql query

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

hi I have  a query question  Join with the recursion . I don't understand how I can linke the every field which is category_id of my product with the category level through the table OS_Product_Category_Mapping.  my query is :

```
    SELECT pr.Id, pr.Name, pr.Sku, ct.category_l2_id, ct.category_l2_name,   
         ct.category_l1_id, ct.category_l1_name, ct.category_l0_id,   
      ct.category_l0_name
    FROM PSV_STG.dbo.OS_Product  as pr
        left join  PSV_STG.dbo.OS_Product_Category_Mapping as prcat 
        on prcat.ProductId =pr.Id
          left join (
          select t1.[Id] category_l2_id,t1.[Name] category_l2_name,t2.Id  
          category_l1_id,t2.Name category_l1_name,t2.ParentCategoryId   
          category_l0_id,t3.Name category_l0_name
             from [PSV_STG].dbo.OS_Category t1
          join (SELECT distinct [Id],[Name],[ParentCategoryId]
             FROM [PSV_STG].dbo.OS_Category 
          where [ParentCategoryId]=(select [Id] 
                from [PSV_STG].dbo.OS_Category
          where [Name]='Каталог' and Deleted=0)) t2 
              on t1.[ParentCategoryId]=t2.Id
            join (select [Id],[Name]
           from [PSV_STG].dbo.OS_Category
          where [Name]='Каталог' and Deleted=0) t3
              on t2.[ParentCategoryId]=t3.Id
          where t1.Deleted=0 and t1.Published=1 ) as ct
        on ct.category_l0_id  = prcat.CategoryId or  ct.category_l1_id =             prcat.CategoryId or ct.category_l2_id = prcat.CategoryId
```

A output  I have 2000 records instead of 300.  I have to relate ct
            on ct.category_l0_id  = prcat.CategoryId or  ct.category_l1_id =             prcat.CategoryId or ct.category_l2_id = prcat.CategoryId

but in another way.

I have to relate every level of my recursion with the product . This query is not right . I don't know how to make this ct on ct.category_l0_id = prcat.CategoryId or ct.category_l1_id = prcat.CategoryId or ct.category_l2_id = prcat.CategoryId inside the recursion

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: I have to relate every level of my recursion with the product . This query is not right . I don't know how to make this  ct
         on ct.category_l0_id  = prcat.CategoryId or  ct.category_l1_id =             prcat.CategoryId or ct.category_l2_id = prcat.CategoryId

  inside the recursion